# How to install npm using command prompt

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, codeigniter, command

```html
npm update check failed                    │
│              Try running with sudo or get access              │
│             to the local update config store via              │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\Acg-Tech\.config
```

I am getting this issue in command prompt. i have tried these commands sudo npm i -g npm, npm i -g npm-upgrade, by running in command prompt but it's not working for me. How to resolve this issue.can anyone please help me.

Comment: Do you have npm and just want to upgrade, or you do not have it at all?

Comment: @Deeksha shetty Do you have node installed on your system?

Comment: @TroyD thank's for your reply i have already installed npm but if i run npm install command in command prompt but it's not working it's showing the error as mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this a windows system you need to run cmd with administrator rights and try it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you don't have it installed. (Even in the case you have it, it can be easily updated by this method).
If you have a Mac, install [Brew](https://brew.sh) and if you are on Windows, [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation) and then follow their respective commands to install/update npm. They will mostly take care of all the necessities to install/download anything.
The command will be mostly:

```
brew/chocolatey install npm
```

Answer (score 0):

Download and install nodejs
Also add nodejs path and npm in roaming folder paths to env variables